# Magento 2 - AWS Lightsail - Bitnami - Password protect development site

Tags: magento2, password, aws

I have followed the below link and added authentication for Bitnami Magento 2.3.2 development site which is in AWS Lightsail.

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/magento/administration/use-htpasswd/

I have created htpasswd and magento_users using,

````
cd /opt/bitnami
apache2/bin/htpasswd -cb apache2/magento_users USERNAME PASSWORD```
````

Also I have added the below code in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/httpd-app.conf

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs">
...
AuthType Basic
AuthName MyAuthName
AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/magento_users"
Require valid-user
...
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
# Require all granted
</IfVersion>
...
</Directory>
```

After I have restarted the apache and flushed the cache, It asked for username and password when loading dev frontend. When I provide credentials, it end up getting error as,

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 393256

Varnish cache server
```

I can't see anything related to this in Apache error_log.

Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have issues with this block in varnish config:

```
.probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;    
}
```

your health_check.php served from **pub/** directory already.
another issue that **probe** time settings were too small and you have sick backend.

you can fix path, extend timings, or remove probe.

check backend status:

> varnishadm backend.list